# WEKA: Discretize continuous attributes

Tags: weka

How do I discretize continuous attributes? When learning a bayesian network, it gives me next warning 'Warning: discretizing data set'.
However, when I try to generate artificial data, all I get is 'All' while I used 75 examples for constructing the bayesian network. This should be enough right?

Do I need to specifiy the amount of bins? If so, how? Do I manually need to discretize the data? If so, how? I have no problems with nominal attributes at all.

Thanks.

Comment: I found out how to discretize. What I do is:
`Discretize filter = new Discretize();
filter.setInputFormat(trainingSet);
Instances trainingSet2 = Filter.useFilter(trainingSet, filter);`
I get something like this:
'\'(0.555-0.616]\'','\'(0.693-0.752]\'','\'(0.454-0.49]\'','\'(0.151-0.212]\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'(0.535-0.566]\'','\'(0.731-inf)\'',7
That's something that comes rather close, but it is still not what I want. (There are 2 'All's)

Comment: If it solves your problem, you should post it as an answer (and accept when you can). There is no reason to keep an open question.

Comment: Edit: I found out that the All values are due to the fact that this attribute only has 1 value for all the examples.
What does 'inf' mean? Does it refer to the biggest/smallest value for this attribute?

Comment: @zero323 My question is partially answered, but not yet completely.

Comment: `inf` means infinity